# Is there a natural language parser for dates/times in ColdFusion?

Tags: datetime, coldfusion, nlp

Is there a [natural language parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) for date/times in ColdFusion?

Comment: For whoever said to close this as an exact duplicate- please edit the question and put in a link to the question this is an exact duplicate of.

Comment: I don't recall seeing even a similar question to this, never mind a duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a (reportedly -- I've not used it) good one for Java called [JChronic](https://github.com/samtingleff/jchronic) -- a port of the Ruby Chronic date parser.  You could try using it.

It hasn't been updated since 2006, but should still be useful.

Answer (score 3):

I believe [parseDateTime()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_m-r_11.html#134381) and [lsParseDateTime()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_l_36.html#133322) are the closest to what you're looking for, from the library of built-in ColdFusion functions.

Check out Adobe's LiveDocs for [other date/time functions](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/functions-pt0_05.html#1098968).

Remember that you can also leverage any Java date/time class as well. Pete Freitag has an [interesting post](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/569.cfm) with some example code.

Comment: natural language, as in tomorrow, yesterday, one week from today, etc.

Comment: @antony- please specify that in the original question if that's what you want.  when you said "natural language", i thought that meant that it can parse a string in any format naturally used.  i.e. the user could enter "1/11/94" or "january 11, 1994" or "1994.01.11" or whatever, and the parser would be smart enough to figure out the format.

Comment: added link to Wikipedia article on NLP

Answer (score -1):

Since you are probably using it in a form anyway checkout [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/), a very nice javascript date library that can parse a lot of dates. It is very easy to incorporate with CF.