# Intelligent date range parsing of human input?

Tags: php, javascript, python, ruby, coldfusion

Has anyone come across a script / cl app written in *any* language that handles the parsing of human-entered dates well? I'd love to be able to parse, for example:

- "3 to 4 weeks"
- "2 - 3 days"
- "3 weeks to 2 months"

Comment: possible duplicate of [fuzzy timestamp parsing with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258712/fuzzy-timestamp-parsing-with-python)

Comment: You can try http://www.datejs.com, it parses well usual date inputs but won't handle your 3 examples. I'm curious... What would you expect as a Javascript date for ie:"3 to 4 weeks"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a natural language parser for dates/times in ColdFusion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003330/is-there-a-natural-language-parser-for-dates-times-in-coldfusion)

Comment: @Mic I'm not sure what would be most useful, but off the top of my head it would be cool if the parser could interpret a "min/max" date range when given a starting date (most often "Now") and a string such as those above. These examples would be "lead time" values in my app - ie, a user responds with a time window in which they can deliver their product.

Comment: @Mic to clarify my above comment: I would expect the hypothetical script to return **two** Date objects given one of the strings above and a starting date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Chronic gem](http://chronic.rubyforge.org/) for ruby will allow you to express dates in a natural form.

Some examples of supported forms (from the documentation)

```
  thursday
  november
  summer
  friday 13:00
  mon 2:35
  4pm
  yesterday at 4:00
  last friday at 20:00
  last week tuesday
  tomorrow at 6:45pm
  afternoon yesterday
  thursday last week
  3 years ago
  5 months before now
  7 hours ago
  7 days from now
  1 week hence
  in 3 hours
  1 year ago tomorrow
```

I have not used it so can not comment on its performance.

Answer (score 0):

Look here:
[Is there a natural language parser for dates/times in ColdFusion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003330/is-there-a-natural-language-parser-for-dates-times-in-coldfusion/1004083#1004083)