# How to extract dates/places in text?

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval, information-extraction

What are the best packages/software for extracting times/dates/places in text?

Or is there any dataset that could be used as dataset?

For example:

> > -- PLEASE JOIN US FOR COOKIES AND COFFEE AT [2:30PM] BEFORE THE SEMINAR IN [ROOM 154 COORDINATED SCIENCE LABORATORY]
> >
> > -- Then we'll meet on [Friday 6 pm] ...
> >
> > -- This week's seminar is moved to Tuesday, from [11:00 am to 12:00pm].
> >
> > Time: [11-12pm], [Oct. 29 Tuesday]
> >
> > Place: [SC 0216]

Title Statistical significance of combinatorial features with frequent itemset mining ....

I can train a machine learning model for such a task, but I don't know any labelled dataset for this. Anyone aware of any labelled dataset?

Comment: There are prevailing systems like Google-Calenders or i-Cal of Apple which do this similar task (and believe me they have attain a very high accuracy) so what you can do is take them as the case study and follow some research papers of it, which algorithms they have used, how they increased the accuracy, etc. This will surely help you. Initially you can try by just using regular expression and then later including some machine learning approaches.

Comment: hi! have you looked at this kind of question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003326/is-there-a-natural-language-parser-for-date-times-in-javascript? it deals with time - not place - parsing, but I'm not sure if what you want is only to be able to locate (and not necessarily parse) time/place expressions in text.