# node.js :How to receive date and time(i.e a particular calendar time ) in Json from the client?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to receive a calendar time from clients(i.e android,ios and web) and store it to mongodb.

What will the client request format ?and How to store it into mongodb using mongoose?

I'm not able to figure out what clients will send.

Please provide any help.

Comment: If you're having node.js in your stack, the most logical would be a RESTful WebServices implementation. Just let the client POST the data to your server.

Comment: mongoose accepts javascript Date object. If you aren't sure about what format the clients will post, you can use one of parser libraries listed here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003326/is-there-a-natural-language-parser-for-date-times-in-javascript